# Cannot create JDBC driver of class "" for connect URL 'null'

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc, mybatis

I am trying to connect to an oracle DB with myBatis and it returns the following error:

```
GRAVE: ERROR.nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
### The error may exist in com/iberdrola/persistence/dao/BusquedaDao.java (best guess)
### The error may involve com.iberdrola.persistence.dao.BusquedaDao.getResultadosBusqueda
### The error occurred while executing a query
### Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
```

I have the DB configuration in the tomcat server.xml

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" maxIdle="1" maxTotal="20" maxWaitMillis="-1" name="jdbc/nombreBD" password="pass" removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//IP:PUERTO/AWDD" username="user"/>
```

I don't understand why it tells me that class is equal to "" and url 'null' when as seen, if I have those settings added.

I don't know what I could be missing or what I could be doing wrong.

Any missing info, I add it without problems.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to integrate Tomcat with iBatis using a configuration similar to the one mentioned below:

```
<transactionManager type="JDBC" >
  <dataSource type="JNDI">
     <property name="DBJndiContext" value="jdbc/nombreBD"/>
  </dataSource>
</transactionManager>
```

Check [this](https://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/DerbyTomcat5512JPetStor.html#iBATIS+Integration+Notes) to learn more about it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I don't have that configuration, I have what I have put above in the tomcat server.xml and in META-INF / context.xml I have the following:

    <ResourceLink global="jdbc/nombreBD" name="nombreBD"  type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

Is it necessary to add what you comment?

Comment: @tripossi - You need to integrate Tomcat with iBatis. Check the update.

Comment: Ok, don´t worry!! I will do what you say. Thank you again Arvind!

Comment: I did it!

I have added the resource that I had in server.xml to the META-INF / context.xml file and also I have added the ojdbc7.jar connector in the local path of tomcat / lib

Comment: Great! Wish you success!